# Is this scraper limited to 99 records or is there a bug?

Tags: .net, web-scraping, httpclient, yahoo-finance

Here's a scraper. It scrapes for records dated from a start date to 2023 July 1. If I set the start date to May 1, it returns the expected quantity of records. If I set it to January 1, it gives me nothing older than February 8. From February 8 to July 1, there are 99 records. Perhaps there is a 99 record limit. However, contrary to that limit, if I paste the URI into Edge web browser, I can get thousands of records. Is there bug in the program? I suspect not, but I am open to the possibility that it can be fixed.

```
internal class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Beep(); // test
        TimeSpan ts;
        ts = new DateTime(2023, 1, 1) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        ulong startTime = Convert.ToUInt64(ts.TotalSeconds);
        ts = new DateTime(2023, 7, 1) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        ulong endTime = Convert.ToUInt64(ts.TotalSeconds);
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        string uri = $"http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/INTC/history?period1={startTime}&period2={endTime}&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d";
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string? html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (html != null)
            {
                Dictionary<DateTime, float> historicalPrices = ParseHistoricalPrices((string)html);
                Console.Beep();
                Console.WriteLine($"historical prices count {historicalPrices.Count}");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
                Console.ReadKey();
                foreach (var kvp in historicalPrices)
                    Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key} {kvp.Value}");
            }
            else throw new Exception();
        }
        else throw new Exception();
    }
    private static Dictionary<DateTime, float> ParseHistoricalPrices(string html)
    {
        Dictionary<DateTime, float> dictionary = new Dictionary<DateTime, float>();
        IElement matchingTable = null;
        AngleSharp.IBrowsingContext browsingContext = BrowsingContext.New(AngleSharp.Configuration.Default);
        AngleSharp.Dom.IDocument document = browsingContext.OpenAsync(virtualResponse => virtualResponse.Content(html)).Result;
        if (document.Title != null)
        {
            if (document.Title.Contains("Historical Prices"))
            {
                int matchCount = 0;
                var tableCollection = document.GetElementsByTagName("table");
                foreach (var table in tableCollection)
                {
                    var dataTestAttribute = table.GetAttribute("data-test");
                    if (dataTestAttribute == "historical-prices")
                    {
                        matchCount++;
                        matchingTable = table;
                    }
                }
                if (matchCount == 1)
                {
                    var tbodyCollection = matchingTable.GetElementsByTagName("tbody");
                    if (tbodyCollection.Length == 1)
                    {
                        var trCollection = tbodyCollection[0].GetElementsByTagName("tr");
                        foreach (var trElement in trCollection)
                        {
                            var tdCollection = trElement.GetElementsByTagName("td");
                            if (tdCollection.Length == 7) // historical price record
                            {
                                string dateString = tdCollection[0].TextContent;
                                string adjCloseString = tdCollection[5].TextContent;
                                dateString = dateString.Trim();
                                adjCloseString = adjCloseString.Trim();
                                adjCloseString = adjCloseString.Replace(",", ""); // remove commas
                                DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MMM dd, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                                Debug.Assert(date.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
                                Debug.Assert(date.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero);
                                float adjClose = (float)Convert.ToDouble(adjCloseString);
                                if (dictionary.ContainsKey(date))
                                    dictionary.Remove(date);
                                dictionary.Add(date, adjClose);
                            }
                            else if (tdCollection.Length == 2)
                            {
                                // ignore
                            }
                            else throw new Exception();
                        }
                    }
                    else throw new Exception();
                }
                else throw new Exception();
            }
            else throw new Exception();
        }
        else throw new Exception();
        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit shocked about all of the `else throw new Exception()` lines...

Comment: Also the `.Result` on tasks are a bit of a worry.

Comment: And you're not disposing disposables. I feel you're making your code fragile before you even start.

Comment: @Enigmativity suppose this code gets pasted into a Windows application. Even with the interactive user interface, if don't have results yet, there's nothing for the user to do. If there is nothing to do but wait, the `.Result` invocation does not lose me anything. Am I right?

Comment: @Enigmativity okay, but I had an earlier version based on the now obsolete WebClient that did an implicit dispose because of using statements and it was still hitting this limit.  Anyway, your point is well taken that this should be tidied up.

Comment: @H2ONaCl it does. For example cancel the operation. Or understand that application is working correctly and not just bugged out (so some kind of feedback or spinner is needed also).

Comment: The URL you're building brings down an initial page with around 99 rows. It's only because of javascript that it loads more. You'll note, though, that's there's a download link on the page that will download the full data in CSV format. Use that. `https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/INTC?period1=1658112093&period2=1689648093&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true`

Comment: @Enigmativity unfortunately the CSV download respects the "interactive" parameters on the webpage. It seems to ignore the URI web query parameters.

Comment: @H2ONaCl - I'm testing it and it works fine.

Comment: @Enigmativity shocking. Maybe it's my ISP.

Comment: @GuruStron Good point about a cancel button. Still it's kind of a disaster to not have data so I never added a cancel button to the Windows version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML page is paging dynamically using Javascript and is only rendering 99 rows on the initial load. Just use the CSV download URL - it pulls the full data.

This works for me:

```
private static async Task<Dictionary<DateTime, decimal>> GetHistoricalPricesAsync(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    ulong GetUnixTime(DateTime value) => Convert.ToUInt64((value - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds);

    ulong startTime = GetUnixTime(new DateTime(2021, 1, 1));
    ulong endTime = GetUnixTime(new DateTime(2021, 2, 1));

    string uri = $"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/INTC?period1={startTime}&period2={endTime}&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true";

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string csv = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
        string[] lines = csv.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.None);
        return lines.Skip(1).Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToDictionary(x => DateTime.Parse(x[0]), x => decimal.Parse(x[4]));
    }
}
```

I can call it like this:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, decimal> output
    = await GetHistoricalPricesAsync(new DateTime(2021, 1, 1), new DateTime(2021, 2, 1));
```

That gives me:

[image: output]

It works fine for a longer time span.